# AngularJS difference between {{ obj }} and {{ ::obj }}

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and see a file written by others with this code:

```
{{ ::set.text }}
```

What does that do vs.

```
{{ set.text }}
```

Both load on the page and I can't tell any difference.

Comment: `::` indicates [one-time-binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)

Comment: Using `::` for a one-time bind is a good performance booster on pages with many scoped variables. Here's a blog post on several Angular performance tricks, including the `::` trick: http://www.alexkras.com/11-tips-to-improve-angularjs-performance#bind-once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{{ :: expression }}` means bind-once. This one will wait for expression to give a result and present that in the template. If the value of the expression changes later the view will not. It will allways display the first value it resolves to.

`{{ expression }}` will evaluate the expression on every digest. If the value of the expression changes the view will update with the new value.

The example below displays the difference. As the app is loaded the variable is not set - and both the paragraphs are empty. As soon as you start typing the value changes and updates the view. But when you type your 2nd character only the 2nd paragraph will update, as the one-time-binding has been set and is no longer watching for changes on the variable.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', function(){});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <p>Bind once: {{ :: variable }}</p>
  <p>Normal binding: {{ variable }}</p>
  
  <div>
    <span>Write to change value of variable:</span>
    <input type="text" ng-model="variable" />
  </div>
<div>
```